# What is the appropriate test for comparing cost per conversion

Tags: t-test

If you have two test campaigns with these results, what test would you use to determine if the resulting cost per conversion is statistically different:

#### Campaign 1:

- 100 clicks
- \$1 per click
- 25% conversion rate
- \$4/conversion

#### Campaign 2:

- 200 clicks
- \$.50 per click
- 10% conversion rate
- \$5/conversion

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you need a model for the expected number of conversions that each campaign generates, and you want inference on the inference on the derived parameter `R = 4*lambda1 - 5*lambda2`
It would be possible to model this in a single step (e.g. by assuming that the number of conversions comes from a Poisson distribution, or other suitable distribution for modeling counts).  In pseudocode, this would look like

```
conversions1 ~ Poisson(lambda1)
conversions2 ~ Poisson(lambda2)
R <- 4*lambda1 - 5*lambda2
```

However, the additional information naturally yields a second, hierarchical model, where you assume that the number of clicks comes from a Poisson distribution, and then the number of conversions comes from a binomal distribution.  In pseudocode, that would look like:

```
clicks1 ~ Poisson(lambda1)
conversions1 ~ binomial(p1, clicks1)
clicks2 ~ Poisson(lambda2)
conversions2 ~ binomial(p2, clicks2)
R <- 4*lambda1*p1 - 5*lambda2*p2
```

This would be a natural (and very easy) model to fit using Winbugs or JAGS--a good excuse to learn this software if you would like.

Comment: I may have stated my question incorrectly, all the conversions have the same value, it's just that because of the difference in CPC, they could have different costs per conversion.

Comment: Could I use the fact that the conversions come from a binomial distribution to somehow derive a SE for the cost per conversion and then use something like a t-test to test for significance?